# Get a error claiming my 2D array is not 2D in impyute

Tags: arrays, pandas, numpy

Here is the shape of my array

```
b = data[0].values
print(b.shape)

(5126, 4229)
```

I get this error when I run this code:

```
from impyute.imputation.cs import mice

# start the MICE training
a=mice(b)
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

I am confused by this error message, any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

First, you must change your input data to a 2D array, so you must specify the number of features in your data using reshape function.

Please try to use b.reshape(5126, 4229), if not try to follow this example until you figure out the problem

[image]

Comment: Please show me the data, if you have it on github or any place

Comment: I could send you a csv if you want?

Comment: Could I get your email?

Comment: hamditarek01@gmail.com

Comment: Just sent it to you

Comment: any luck? Let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: sorry, I will check it tomorrow, it's too late here

Comment: Did you have a chance to look at the dataset?